# Absolute module path resolution in TypeScript files in Visual Studio Code

Tags: module, typescript, visual-studio-code

I can't seem to convince Visual Studio Code to resolve absolute TypeScript module paths. Relative paths work, but absolute don't. I would like Visual Studio Code to resolve module paths from `./src` folder on.

```
// This works when source file is in /src/here/there/file.ts
// and importing an interface in /src/api/interfaces.ts
import { Interface } from '../../api/interfaces';

// This doesn't work
import { Interface } from 'api/interfaces';
import { Interface } from '/api/interfaces';
import { Interface } from 'src/api/interfaces';
import { Interface } from '/src/api/interfaces';

// This works, but it is of course not supposed to be used
import { Interface } from 'c:/..../src/api/interfaces';
```

The last one of course doesn't count as each developer's project path is highly likely different. But even if we'd all set a system variable `%ProjectXRoot%` we can't use this variable in the code. Visual Studio Code will not resolve such module path. I've tried.

```
// Won't work
import { Interface } from '%ProjectXRoot%/api/interfaces';
```

> **Currently installed versions** 
> • TypeScript: 1.8.10 
> • VSCode: 1.1.1

### Question

I've tried to somehow configure Visual Studio Code to resolve absolute module paths, but I can't seem to do so. I've tried configuring *tsconfig.json* (in the project root) by adding `baseUrl` in two different places.

```
{
    ...
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./src", // Doesn't work
        ...
    },
    "baseUrl": "./src", // Doesn't work either
    ...
}
```

I've tried values like `src`, `./src` and `./src/`, but none of them work in any of the upper configuration places.

So *how does one configure Visual Studio Code* to resolve absolute module paths from a certain folder?

If that's not possible, it would be at least better to resolve absolute paths from project root. How does Visual Studio Code determine that? Is it where you *Open Folder* or is it where the *.vscode* folder is?

But it would still be a viable solution for absolute paths. I've tried using `~` similar to Visual Studio, but to no avail either.

<sup>(Unresolved)</sup>

--
As *steinso* points out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37606571/absolute-module-path-resolution-in-typescript-files-in-vscode/37655471#37655471), all modules starting with `/`, `./` or `../` are considered relative. Especially the first one surprised me completely as I usually consider that a project root-relative path.

But this fact basically means that the **main question** now becomes: **How can I provide module imports as absolute paths** <sup>(from some *project* root folder path)</sup> at all? Starting paths with slashes usually meant absolute, but in this case it doesn't.

Even when I set compiler option `moduleResolution` to `classic` (so module resolution wont be looking into `node_modules` folder) the second set of imports above should actually **all work** as per Microsoft's linked document. But for some reason I still get red squiggly lines in Visual Studio Code and errors during compilation.

So how can I **import a specific project module without providing an exact relative path** to it, but rather just its own project-relative path?

Comment: I've provided an answer that works with `typescript@next` and some minor configurations.

Comment: I got this to work by adding "include" to my tsconfig: (e.g. `"include": ["js/*"]`) https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Answer (score 31):

To be able to use absolute paths from import in TypeScript using Visual Studio Code you should be using next version of TypeScript - `typescript@next` which is TypeScript v2. For that do the following:

1. Install *typescript@next* via npm. For installing TypeScript v2.x

   `npm i typescript@next -D`
2. In Visual Studio Code

   i) Go to menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Workspace Settings* (This generates the `.vscode` directory at the project root and initializes the `settings.json` file.)

   ii) Put the following `key:value` pair in `settings.json` file

   `"typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib"`
3. In `tsconfig.json` add following key:value pair to `'compilerOptions'`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions" : {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths" : {
      "src/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

4. Reload Visual Studio Code

If you have the following directory structure:

```
+ node_modules
+ src
| + app
| |  + shared
| |  |  -service.ts
| |  -main.ts
+ typings
- tsconfig.json
- webpack.config.json
- package.json
- index.html
```

Then to import `/src/app/shared/service.ts` from `main.ts` you could now `import {} from 'src/app/shared/service`;

If you are using `webpack` and `ts-loader` for transpiling the `.ts` files, you should add following to the `resolve` section of `webpack.config.js` configuration file.

```json
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts'],
    alias: {
      "src": path.resolve('./src')
    }
  }
```

Please refer to [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039) for absolute module resolution.

Comment: Tried this, but it doesn't work for me. To import `<project-root>/addon/thing.ts` from `<project_root>/tests/unit/thing-test.ts`, I do `import thing from 'my-module/thing';`. I can't use a relative import b/c of the way ember-cli builds the addon (there's a dummy app in which the tests run). `ln -s ../addon node_modules/my-module` enables vscode to resolve the module, but that's not sustainable. I'm using typescript@2.0.0 w/ broccoli-typescript-compiler@0.6.2. My `tsconfig.json` includes `{"compilerOptions": {"baseUrl" : "./", "paths": {"my-module/*": ["./addon/*"]}}}`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify:

```
    "compilerOptions": {
        "moduleResolution": "classic"
        ...
```

<strike>The base path will then default to the directory of your tsconfig.json, add  `rootDir` in compilerOptions to change it.</strike> EDIT: This does not seem to have any effect.

This will allow imports such as:

```
import { Interface } from 'api/interfaces';
```

Note that any path starting with `.` or `../` or `/` is considered relative.

**Edit:** Module resolution

Be aware of how the modules are resolved. The module path is still some what relative to the current file.

Let's use an example to illustrate for the current scenario:

Let's say you `import { Interface } from "api/interfaces"`, from source file `/src/views/View.ts`. Typescript would then look for the module in the following paths:

1. /src/views/`api/interfaces.ts`
2. /src/`api/interfaces.ts`
3. /`api/interfaces.ts`

**Note:** how this still makes it relative, imagine if you `import {Home} from "Home/Home"` when you are located in `/src/views/View.ts`. In this case it would work even if the path is `/src/views/Home/Home`.

These are the possible resolutions:

1. /src/views/`Home/Home` -> Note how this would work.
2. /src/`Home/Home`
3. /`Home/Home`

More information can be found here: 
http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Comment: **Desn't seem to work**. the only thing I learned here is that providing `/` at the beginning is not project root, but rather relative path. So my problem is now reduced as per updated question.

Comment: That is weird, we use this on our project, and VSCode does not have any issue with it. All paths are relative to our js/ directory, and using the syntax that I specified. Typescript 1.8.9, VSCode 1.1.1.

Comment: I used typescript 1.5.3, but upgraded (`npm -i -g typescript@1.8.10`) and restarted VSCode (1.1.1) but without any difference. So I'm basically using newer version of TS than you do. Does it make any difference if you remove the `moduleResolution` or change to `node` which is the default anyway?

Comment: I changed moduleResolution to 'node' and after some time I got an error on all my imports. However I found that that the rootDir seemed to have no effect. 

I have also updated my answer with more detail as to how the resolution actually works, in case this is where your problem lies.

Comment: Also make sure there are no errors in your tsconfig.json file, for example listed files that do not exist.

Comment: I did have **files** and **exclude** inside, but that's basically not an error. Just a warning that **files** take precedence. Btw. When you changed module resolution (or any other setting in `tsconfig.json`) did you have to restart VSCode or is that not necessary? Or at least reopen the code file that makes na import?

Comment: I did not have to restart VSCode, it just took some time until it updated (ie. 20 seconds -ish). The reason I mentioned tsconfig, was that I experienced suddenly that all my imports failed, and it turned out the reason was that I had deleted a file without deleting the entry in tsconfig.json. VSCode did not notify me of this error and I had to spend some time to track it down.

Comment: Actually, it looks like I have to change a file for it to take effect. Ie. add a new line.

Answer (score 5):

If you've set up paths correctly:

```json
{
  …
  "compilerOptions": {
    …
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["app/assets/javascript/*"],
      "*": ["node_modules/*", "app/assets/javascript/packs/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

And if you're still having issues, maybe try reloading Visual Studio Code: <kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and type `reload window`.

It just randomly stopped working for me and is reporting problems. I spent around 20 minutes online trying to figure out what changed, only to realize that Visual Studio Code can glitch on absolute path resolution.

Comment: For the rest of us, it is Shift + Ctrl + P.