# Refering / Importing classes from typings / other project

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a SPA application in Visual Studio which is written in TypeScript (2.0) and using Aurelia. But my problems is not specific to Aurelia or VS.

Now I would like to write *plugins* for this application in another project. These plugins will have to refer/import classes/modules from the main application.

This basically works but the plugin project does not know about the classes/modules from the main application. Therefore although things compile and run correctly (thanks to JavaScript), the IDE (Visual Studio, VS Code or the NPM typescript compiler) complains **Cannot find module 'abc'** on any import. This also means there is no Intellisense or auto-complete support on those classes.

I have no created the declarations (`*.d.ts`) in the main project and created a build task to copy those to the plugin project. But still they get not recognized. **How can I have the plugin project to recognize these classes coming from declaration files?**

The main app has a class like *core/events.ts*. Its DTS might look like this:

```
export declare class Events {
    static MY_CONSTANT: string;
}
```

The plugin project has a plugin here: *Plugins/PluginA/plugin-panel.ts*. It likes to import `Events` from *core/events.ts*:

```
import { Events as e1 } from 'core/events';
import { Events as e2 } from 'typings/core/events';
```

The first line (**e1**) is like I would import `Events` in the main project and it actually works when the compiled javascript file is dropped into the application. But the compiler complains about it (*semantic error*).

The second line (**e2**) has no compiler warning but is incorrect in runtime.

The typings have been copied to *Plugins/typings/*, here *Plugins/typings/core/events.d.ts*. Only the *Plugins* folder contains TypeScript files, the rest of the project is C#. There is a *tsconfig.json* in the root folder which will be of interest I guess:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "./",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "amd",
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noResolve": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "./Plugins/**/*.ts",
    "./Plugins/typings/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

I already tried to set `rootDir` to *./Plugins* but that did not help either.

How can I set up the project that the import statement works the same in plugin development and deployed in the application?

Note: When I add a mapping for the import in the main application loader configuration (which is `config.js` for `SystemJS` I am using here, the line looks like this: `"typings/core/events": "core/events",`), the main application can work with the different import path. But that would require me to setup a mapping for every typescript file in the main project.

Answer (score 1):

While researching for another `import` problem I found this question: [Absolute module path resolution in TypeScript files in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38336075/573870). Note that I am linking to the answer of Lekhnath.

Apparently TypeScript 2.0 has a new `baseUrl` compiler option which sets the resolve base paths for modules with relative path!

So I can resolve modules/classes from my typings by adding to my `compilerOptions`:

```
"baseUrl": "./Plugins/typings/"
```

This works in Visual Studio, the command line compiler and VS Code (note that VS Code needs a configuration setting to use the project local typescript compiler).