# How to force the compiler to recalculate the way (compilerOptions.paths) in relative?

Tags: typescript

I made a component library under React to TypeScript. In the **tsconfig.json** prescribed the following:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
...
"paths": {
  "@lib": ["src/lib"],
  "@lib/*": ["src/lib/*"]
}
```

Now, instead

```
import {} from '../../../from/field/ComboBox';
```

I write more briefly:

```
import {} from '@lib/from/field/ComboBox';
```

During development, these paths are normally computed. However, after you build and publish the package in another project where the library is connected, you receive an error:

```
build/dist/lib/form/combo/ComboBox.d.ts
(3,40): Cannot find module '@lib/form/list/List'.
```

How to make the compiler recalculate these paths to relative ones when building?

Answer (score 0):

solutions:

http://goenning.net/2017/07/21/how-to-avoid-relative-path-hell-javascript-typescript-projects/

See last answer:
[Absolute module path resolution in TypeScript files in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37606571/absolute-module-path-resolution-in-typescript-files-in-vscode)

with ts-simple-ast):
https://gist.github.com/rifler/e6123e90e172814fe23d5a6a11ed5eb1