# Absolute import typescript react native works partially

Tags: typescript, react-native, absolute-path

I have followed this guide to set up absolute imports in my project..
Did what the third comment of Lekhnath suggested here:
[Absolute module path resolution in TypeScript files in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37606571/absolute-module-path-resolution-in-typescript-files-in-vscode) 
found myself able to do this perfectly fine:

```
import { AppActions } from 'src/BL/redux/types/app-actions.types';
```

it did work. However this doesnt:

```
import { startLoading, stopLoading } from 'src/BL/redux/action-creators/app-action-creators';
```

I have to mention that the import is fine, it even autocomplets me and everything however when I run it fails in this component and says that it can't resolve module action-creators..
This is the component:

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import { AppState } from 'react-native';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useActions } from '../../../BL/redux/useActions';
import { EAAccount } from './EAAccount.interfaces';
import { isVerifiedCredentials } from './EAAccount.logic';
import NewEAAccountForm from './newEAAccountForm.view';
import { Dispatch } from 'redux';
import { AppActions } from 'src/BL/redux/types/app-actions.types';
import { startLoading, stopLoading } from 'src/BL/redux/action-creators/app-action-creators';

    const ConnectEAAccount: FC = () => {
      const dispatch = useDispatch<Dispatch<AppActions>>();
      const onSubmit = async (credentials: EAAccount) => {
        dispatch(startLoading());
        const { isVerified, err } = await isVerifiedCredentials(credentials);
        if (isVerified) {
          alert('success');
        } else alert(err);
        dispatch(stopLoading());
      };

      return <NewEAAccountForm onSubmit={onSubmit} />;
    };
```

When I change

```
import { startLoading, stopLoading } from 'src/BL/redux/action-creators/app-action-creators';
```

to a relative import it does work.
Also has the same problem here where store is not resolved:

```
import store from 'src/BL/redux/configureStore';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <IconRegistry icons={EvaIconsPack} />
        <ApplicationProvider {...eva} theme={eva.dark}>
          <ConnectEAAccount />
        </ApplicationProvider>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks ahead for your help and time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add package.json file inside the src folder that contains:

```
{
    "name":"src"
}
```

each folder you want to use absolute paths on you have to add package.json to it.

Also the

```
"paths" : {
      "src/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
```

is not needed.