# Angular 10: VSCode show error when import with absolute path

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

after Angular 10 upgrade from Angular 9. VSCode show error when import with absolute path:

```
import { IconModule } from 'src/app/shared/components/icon/icon.module';
```

the error:

> Cannot find module 'src/app/shared/components/icon/icon.module'.ts(2307)

if i change with a relative path it works. The same path works if downgrade to Angular 9.

My tsconfig setting:

./tsconfig.json

```
{
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

./src/tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "main.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ]
}
```

./tsconfig.base.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "target": "es2015",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "jszip": [
        "node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js"
      ]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  },
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Absolute module path resolution in TypeScript files in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37606571/absolute-module-path-resolution-in-typescript-files-in-vscode)

Answer (score 2):

Seems, the problem happens because of your `tsconfig` files location. It located in `src` folder already, and `"baseUrl": "./"` linked to that folder. So in your absolute path no need to write `src` folder. Just start from `app`.
Like `'app/shared/components/icon/icon.module'`.

Or move your `tsconfig` files up to root.

Comment: Try to move ./src/tsconfig.app.json to the root. Don't forget change relative paths in tsconfig files.

Comment: yes it works, but moving the file i break the Angular project template...

Comment: If you won't break your template, just refactor your absolute paths to start with "app", not "src", as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: import { IconModule } from 'app/shared/components/icon/icon.module';

Answer (score 2):

Update VSCode to the latest version (1.46.1) has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue caused because of opening a sub-folder in VSCode where import consists of absolute paths and those absolute paths starts from a parent folder of your currently opened folder.

Fix: Open your project's root directory in VSCode