# Visual Studio Code fails to resolve absolute imports for spec files

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

Minor Note: If this question should be deleted or instead posted to the the Visual Studio Code bug form, please let me know and I will do so.

## The Problem

Using Angular workspaces Visual Studio Code cannot resolve absolute or path based imports in spec files. These imports work in non-spec files exactly as expected as well as relative imports in spec files. The real reason as to why I am confident that this is a Visual Studio Code specific issue is that running Angular tests via the command line still completes successfully. Every test runs without complaint. Additionally, I was able to use IntelliJ (Goland) with an Angular plugin and the spec files behave properly in that editor concerning imports.

### The background

I created an Angular workspace with one library and two consuming applications following [this tutorial](https://octoperf.com/blog/2019/08/22/kraken-angular-workspace-multi-application-project/#angular-multi-application-project-creation-tutorial). I've configured a base tsconfig.json file at the root level, additionally in each project a tsconfig.json and a tsconfig.spec.json exists with each referenced by the angular.json. Again I'm confident that each of these files are formatted correctly as the tests/build still work. If it matters, Karma + Jasmine is the test configuration currently being used.

### Attempts to solve

There are a ton of posts, like [Visual Studio Code doesn't recognize absolute import in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70911893/visual-studio-code-doesnt-recognize-absolute-import-in-typescript), which indicate that the tsconfig is misconfigured and trying each and every possible fix can be daunting. Suffice it to say that I tried many of the proposed solutions, none of which worked for me.

### The files

Here are the tsconfig files for one of the projects.

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./", <---- These imports work in non-spec files 
    "paths": { <---- These imports work in non-spec files
      "myLibrary": [
        "./../../dist/my-library/my-library",
        "./../../dist/my-library"
      ]
    },
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

`tsconfig.spec.json`

```json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine", "node"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "./", <---- These imports don't work in spec files
    "paths": { <---- These imports don't work in spec files
      "myLibrary": [
        "./../../dist/my-library/my-library",
        "./../../dist/my-library"
      ]
    },
  },
  "files": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

The root level `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* many different options, but the paths and baseUrl options are not set */
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

### Some other hints

In addition to the relative and path based imports not working the describe/beforeEach/it/expect functions that jasmine provides are not detected. In IntelliJ these resolve to `node_modules/@types/jasime/index.d.ts` but in Visual Studio Code the error prompted is `Cannot find name 'describe'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? ts(2582)`. However I'm hesitant to put much stock on this because sometimes those functions do resolve correctly, I'm not sure why it is inconsistent. As previously mentioned, relative imports work, I know the baseUrl property controls how absolute imports work, but I'm not sure how Visual Studio Code handles relative imports. Either way, it can do it successfully.

Overall, I'm hoping to find some solution that will allow me to keep using vs-code because I like the editor. However, writing tests is a big part of the project, and if imports don't work, then the editor is unusable.